# Flag pop-up does not work in deleted question

Tags: bug, flags, deleted-questions

I am trying to access the flag pop-up in [this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77404557/supervised-or-unsupervised-learning-classification-facebook-prophet-vs-arima), in order to retract a custom flag that is no longer needed (since the question is now deleted); but every time I try I get the following message:

> Unable to load popup - please try again

I am fairly certain that I have done this several times in the past in similar occasions, and the message implies that it is indeed an error (and not some new functionality that forbids opening the flag pop-up in deleted questions).

I can access the pop-up without any issues in existing (i.e. non-deleted) questions. Restarting my PC did not remedy the issue.

So, is it a bug or what?

I'm using Firefox 113.0.2 (64-bit) in Ubuntu.

Comment: The flag menu shows up for me in that question. It only has modflag available (which is expected). Might have been a temporary issue or maybe it's something related to your account preventing it.

Comment: Works for me as well, do you have some very aggressive ad / tracker / javascript blocking enabled? Any plugins that might interfere? Maybe also add the browser (and OS) you're using as it could be a browser / OS specific issue.

Comment: I was unable to duplicate this issue after raising a flag on a deleted question on MSE. It would be helpful if you could look in the browser console to see if A) what, if any, errors are reported; and B) what your browser shows as the response to the AJAX request which gets the flag popup. What you're wanting to do should work.

Comment: Thanks @Makyen; strangely enough, the flag pop-up works as expected in [this deleted SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77411098/kl-divergence-in-vae-how-is-it-calculated-for-different-use-cases) (where I have not raised a flag already), but the behavior I have reported above in the subject question remains.

Comment: Maybe the steps to reproduce involve flagging the question, then the question being deleted, then attempting to access the flag menu? All of the comments seem to indicate no-repro on already-deleted questions.

Comment: I had a pending flag on a now deleted question (Flag was raised before deletion), can't reproduce this issue.